# Unable to pass ARGV through Test Unit (ruby)

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, testunit

I'm running automation tests with watir-webdriver.
I am not able to pass command line arguments ARGV through test unit, I get an ArgumentError.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'    
ARGV.each do |arg|
        if arg.downcase.include? 'chrome'
            $browser = 'chrome'
        elsif arg.downcase.include? 'firefox'
            $browser = 'firefox'
        elsif arg.downcase.include? 'ff'
            $browser = 'firefox'
        elsif arg.downcase.include? 'ie'
            $browser = 'ie'
        end
    end

class TEST_SITE < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def setup
     if $browser == 'chrome'
        $b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
     elsif $browser == 'firefox'
        $b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
     elsif $browser == 'ie'
        $b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
     end
  end
end
```

Is there another option or somehow override the test unit class?

Comment: Your code worked for me. I called it using 'ruby filename.rb ff', etc.

Comment: I am calling it via commandline 'ruby filename.rb chrome'. @JustinKo, Did you include the required files too?

Comment: I copied the exact code that you have above into a file and then ran it from command prompt. Can you add the full exception that you are seeing?

Comment: I am getting the error below : C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: ff (ArgumentError)

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I am using Ruby 1.8.7, which does not have this issue. I see your problem now when I use Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test/Unit seems to have logic around how it is handling the values in ARGV, though not exactly sure what values it is checking for. However, if you make your arguments more parameter like, they get ignored by Test/Unit and your tests should run.

Try running the following from command line (you should not need to change your code):

```
ruby filename.rb -browser=ff
```